# PHP: Cannot seem to trap FALSE value returned by PDO DB Connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following function in a database connection class:

```
function connect() {
        //create PDO instance
        // Check if connection is already established
        if ( self::$connection == false) {
            $dsn = "$this->driver:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbName;charset=$this->charset";
            try {
                self::$connection = new PDO($dsn,self::$user, self::$passCode, self::$connectionOptions);
                return self::$connection;
            } catch ( PDOException $error ) {
                return FALSE;
            }   
        }else{
                return self::$connection; 
        }
    }
```

The problem I am having is that when I insatiate an object, I cannot trap the returned FALSE if a DB connection doesn't exist. So when in my object I do

```
self::$dbh = new Dbc($tableName);
```

i am not able to check for a returned NULL or FALSE... my code carries on as if the connection exists (and therefore produces errors.

I have tried:

```
self::$dbh = new Dbc($tableName);
if (!self::$dbh){
   ...error code
}
```

and

```
if (!self::$dbh = new Dbc($tableName)){
    ...error code
}
```

I have also tried checking for false/FALSE/null/NULL, is_null(self::$dbh) and nothing is returning the false/null value.

For testing i have set every variable/attribute to PUBLIC.

Would really appreciate if you could help me stop scratching my head... it's starting to bleed!

Comment: That's wrong function to have and wrong question to ask. I don't even see why you expect any return value from new Dbc() while returning false from the connect() function. Anyway, please, don't use this class, don't use this function, don't try to report database errors manually. Create a PDO connection the usual way and pass it as a constructor parameter into all other classes that need it

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.